# How to detect and assert virtual inheritance for a specific class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have a C++ class that implements reference-counting and I want all users of this class to inherit from this class only virtually so that no object ends up with more than one reference counter.

I'd like some way to assert this requirment either during compile time or  at least during runtime.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think wrapping the class would be the simplest option. Rather than directly inheriting from RefCounter create an intermediary class.

```
struct RefCounterVirtPrivate_
{
    int count;

    RefCounterVirt()
        : count( 0 )
    { }
};

struct RefCounter : public virtual RefCounterVirtPrivate_
{
};

struct A : public RefCounter { };
struct B : public RefCounter { };
struct C : public A, public B { };
```

Then everything can inherit from `RefCounter` without any need to care about virtual inheritence. You don't even have to change any existing code -- virtual inheritence of `RefCounter` itself should be harmless.

This of course doesn't guarantee people don't inherit from `RefCounterVirtPrivate_` directly, but that is why I've given it an obvious name. It's harder to accidentally do this than forget a `virtual` keyword.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

```
struct RefCounter {
    template <typename T>
    RefCounter(T *) {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_virtual_base_of<RefCounter, T>);
    }
};

struct GoodClass : virtual RefCounter {
    GoodClass() : RefCounter(this) {}
};

struct BadClass : RefCounter {
    BadClass() : RefCounter(this) {}
};
```

It's a shame about needing to pass `this` to the constructor, though, to capture the derived type. And of course a wilfully obtuse user could subvert it by passing something other than `this`.

Comment: You could use CRTP instead of `this`, but I think your solution is better.

Comment: @sbi: I considered that, but then `RefCounter<Derived>` and `RefCounter<DoublyDerived>` would be different classes, and so even if they are virtual you could still end up with multiple refcounter base class subobjects.

Comment: Will this work if a class inherits from two bases and one base inherits from the `RefCounter` virtually and the other inherits non-virtually?

Comment: @sharptooth: the "other" class should trigger the assert, so you wouldn't even get as far as the class that inherits from both of them.

Comment: The solution looks great, except one thing - it requires to actually change each class that already inherits from `RefCounter` and that's quite a lot of work.

Comment: @sharptooth: I think there is a problem, though, with a class that has two bases: `GoodClass` and `RefCounter`. Then `RefCounter` is a virtual base of the class, but is *also* a non-virtual base.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with some trickery, but consider the implications: you are setting the policy that the object needs to immediately self-destruct if its reference counter ever reaches zero.

Depending on your application, you might want to leave the exact time when it calls `delete this;` to the implementation of the object, i.e. only have `add_ref()` and `release()` abstract functions in the base class (which makes the one concrete implementation show up in all interface vtables with proper thunking) and place the burden of maintaining the reference count on the concrete class.

Comment: Actually this class does `delete this` itself at all times, so I could do the checks in `addref()`/`release()`. So the trickery is welcome.